# AWS CLI downloading lambda package as few bytes?

Tags: macos, command-line, aws

```
url=$(aws lambda get-function --function-name my_func --query 'Code.Location' --output text)
```

When I do wget url, it shows:

```
--2022-11-21 11:09:03--  http://url/
Resolving url (url)... 23.217.x.x, 23.202.x.x
Connecting to url (url)|23.217.138.x|:x... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 355 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.2’

index.html.2                                 100%[=============================================================================================>]     355  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2022-11-21 11:09:04 (14.1 MB/s) - ‘index.html.2’ saved [355/355]
```

This html file is only a few KBs. While downloading the url from chrome, it's correct at 10mbs.

What's going wrong?

Here's the HTML (kbs) file's content

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://searchguide.level3.com/search/?q=http://url%2F%26akaCid%3Daaaaaaaa%26t%3D0%26bc%3D"/>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">window.location="http://searchguide.level3.com/search/?q="+escape(window.location)+"&r="+escape(document.referrer)+"&t=0&akaCid=aaaaaaaa&bc=";</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the content of the downloaded file?

Comment: @nohillside a lambda zip file of 10 mbs

Comment: @nohillside oh you mean the html 300 kbs

Comment: <html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://searchguide.level3.com/search/?q=http://url%2F%26akaCid%3Daaaaaaaa%26t%3D0%26bc%3D"/></head><body><script type="text/javascript">window.location="http://searchguide.level3.com/search/?q="+escape(window.location)+"&r="+escape(document.referrer)+"&t=0&akaCid=aaaaaaaa&bc=";</script></body></html>

Comment: Please edit the question to add the html code there. It looks like the HTML file indicates that the actual content is somewhere else (and Chromse probably does the refresh automatically), but let's look at the full content.

Comment: done @nohillside

Comment: As assumed: you need to parse the HTML file to get at the actual content. The folks over at Unix&Linux might be able to help, I‘ll migrate the question.